# POST form from jquery-mobile (android app) to a cakephp website

Tags: android, jsonp

I search a tutorial for learn how to send data from an android application (simple form - application builded with jquery-mobile) to my website under cakephp. I see the JSONP technology, this is the good way, no ? or there is more solutions ?

Comment: JSONP is good to send param across the platform. so go ahead with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP is one way to achive Cross-Domain resource sharing. It is easy on server side just wrap your JSON response with

callback(<-JSON->)

and on client side have unction named callback that take json in argument.

You can also simply change server config to allow all origin so that you won't run into CDRS.